# How to sort objects in a sprite without blinking?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

```
    public function resort():void {

        while (tickets.numChildren > 0) {
            tickets.removeChildAt(tickets.numChildren - 1);
        }

        for(var i:int = 0; i < ticketsBought.length; i++)
        {
            var t:TicketCard = ticketsBought[i] as TicketCard;
            tickets.addChild(t);

        }


    }
```

after this function executes, the tickets are blinking visually, but I don't want that, is there a way to sort objects in the stage without blinking?

Comment: Do you have any condition in the rest of your code that results in blinking? Does `ticketsBought` change by `tickets.removeChildAt()`? Otherwise it seems you are performing the same `for-loop` with the same values a few times.

Comment: no no, its because its removes all the child, and adds them again, to show visually the resorted objects

Comment: no need in removing and adding. try to simply sort them by giving them new depths with the `setChildIndex` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `setChildIndex` method of the `DisplayObjectContainer` class (see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex%28%29)) to reorder your objects without removing and then re-adding them.

Unfortunately I'm not in a position to test this at the moment, but I think the following should work:

```
public function resort():void {

    for(var i:int = 0; i < ticketsBought.length; i++)
    {
        var t:TicketCard = ticketsBought[i] as TicketCard;
        tickets.setChildIndex(t, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nae bother! Good luck with your project.